# SharePoint 2007 list to SSIS 2013 - options?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, ssis

We are in the process of upgrading our SQL servers from 2008 R2 to 2014 (VS data tools 2013) and I am updating all my SSIS packages accordingly.

The issue I am having is trying to make a SSIS package that pulls information from a Sharepoint 2007 list into SQL to work. Until now I have been using the [Sharepoint List Source](https://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652) that worked fine. Problem is that the component seems not to be working with SQL 2014. After looking for an alternative, I found the [OData source](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3220/using-the-new-odata-source-in-sql-server-integration-services/) to do the same thing. As far as I understood though, OData is available only after Sharepoint 2010 (correct me if I am wrong). In any case any attempt to make it connect to my lists have failed.

That leaves me in the strange position of trying to connect 2 end systems with 2 tools that support either the one or the other but not both at the same time.

Has anyone successfully used SSDT 2013 to pull data from a Sharepoint 2007 list? If so how did you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to "roll your own"...Create a web service and use it in a script component